# How can I have an image that changes every 3 seconds in react native?

Tags: react-native

I have a collection of 3 images.
I want the image to change every 3 seconds, how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

```
const IMAGES = ['Link1', 'Link2', 'Link3']

const [index, setIndex] = useState(0)

useEffect(()=>{
  const interval = setInterval(() => {
    setIndex((index+1)%3)
  }, 500);

  return ()=> { interval && clearInterval(interval) }
}, [])

return (
  <Image src={IMAGES[index]} />
)
```

Do try to use an image caching library it will help you avoid loading images repeatedly